# Content-Type in Content negotiation

Tags: json, rest, http, http-headers, http-status-code-406

I'm having trouble understanding something about Content Negotiation in HTTP protocol.

I understand that when the header Accept is sent in a request, it's telling the server that it expects the response in that format.

For instance, if the Header Accept have the value `application/json` then the server must send the response in JSON format. If it can't do this, it sends the HTTP error `406 Not Acceptable` (although most web applications don't do it because the end user would not understand want happen. This is specified so in documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406).

**My problem** is if the request send in the header `Content-Type` the format in which it intends to receive the representation of the resource in the response, and the server application respects this mechanism (content negotiation) then the header `Content-Type` of the response must have the same value if not, then it must be returned the HTTP error `406 Not Acceptable`?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP specification [says](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> If an Accept header field is present, and if the server cannot send a response which is acceptable according to the combined Accept field value, then the server SHOULD send a 406 (not acceptable) response.

Note that ["SHOULD"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) means:

> This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and  carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

So what you think is not true.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear, but i realize that about the Accept header, my problem is if the same thing happen with the header Content-Type in a get request to specify the format of the response the server must send.

Comment: Your question is not clear, indeed. Note that MUST is not the same as SHOULD.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought that it was clear since i mention that it MUST if the server application respects the Content negotiation mechanism.

Comment: No, you misunderstand the specifications. The server SHOULD. It can behave different from what you expect if there are good reasons.